# Impersonate in Classic ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic, impersonation, access-denied

Preparing for the migration of asp-application with Windows 2000 (web1) on Windows 2003 (web2). 
On the old server has a folder to share documents, use for imports and exports (\ \ web1 \ folder). I want to provide access to the same folder access asp-application with the new server. 
Configuration IIS: anonymous access is allowed, including checking windows. Pool started under the Network Service. 
But there is no access. 
And there is an interesting fact: if handled locally with the new server as http://localhost, you have access (impersonation works), if handled as http://web2, then there is no access. Error:

> ```
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error Error '800a0046 ' 
>
> Permission denied
> ```

We some changed security settings, local IE 6 - earned through http://web2 too, but in other browsers (like Opera) does not work. On other machines does not work either.

Put utility procmon from SysInternal. It shows that in both cases is an appeal to the resource, in both cases is impersonation, all the same, but in one case, SUCCESS, and the other ACCESS DENIED.

The entire security system of this application is based on the rights of NTFS, so you can not disable impersonation.

I'm newby in classic asp. I can not understand this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic ASP does not run under Application Pool account, credentials provided in IIS Anonimous Authenctication tab used instead, usually it is IUSR_MACHINENAME.

Looks like the anonymous authentication fails and Windows authentication used, this is the reason it works locally and in IE which supports Windows authentication by default.

**UPDATE:** Check this article: [How to troubleshoot Kerberos-related issues in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326985/en-us)

**UPDATE 2:** Also this can help you diagnose what's going on on IIS side: [Authentication and Access Control Diagnostics](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e90fe777-4a21-4066-bd22-b931f7572e9a)

I guess the simplest way to access share is to add read permission to Guests group.

Comment: Why Windows authentication not work in LAN? I use domain account for access in both case.

Comment: @GraDea Because when you access `http://localhost ` it is safe for IE to pass your Windows credentials to IIS as IE knows this is your local machine.  But when accessing `http://web2` this is unsafe as IE has to assume this is an internet server and therefore it is **unsafe** to pass your Windows credentials to the server

Comment: @GraDea It may be possible to configure IE to pass your Windows Credentials when accessing `http://web2` but I would strongly recommend that you **don't do this** as it is a serious security risk

Comment: I view headers in Fiddler. I have authorisation-header in both case.

Comment: New facts. We investigate our problem. We've added a role of domain controller on a new Web-server (the old server was a domain controller). All fine works after that.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the user of the anonymous authentication to be the app pool user , i tested it and it works !
go to iis -> web site \ virtual directory -> authentication -> choose anonymous -> edit -> change user identity to application pool user

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! But I cant check that settings. I think we tried apppool identity.